# How to integrate soundcloud sdk in android application...!

Tags: java, android, soundcloud

I tried googling that's cause i am  found 2 methods [code.google.com/p/soundcloudapi-java/](http://code.google.com/p/soundcloudapi-java/)

in that step-1 occurred

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer**

i tried to found that solution but not got success anyone can help to sort out these bug......

am i trying to second one

[github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper](http://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper) so please suggest how to use it

Thanks in Advance...!!!! 
[i am including these library file...!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw1io.jpg)

Comment: You need to have the required jar files in the classpath of your application at runtime.

Comment: show my jar files which one is including me is that correct ...

Comment: In your first link, in the Getting Started section, it is clearly explained which jar files you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake and how to integrate the sound-cloud SDK.

```
// Create a wrapper instance
ApiWrapper wrapper = new ApiWrapper("client_id", "client_secret", null, null, Env.LIVE);
```

Here, initialization of the `ApiWrapper` class pass old argument `null` at position of `Env.LIVE*` but in the new SDK it passes out `Env.LIVE` the parameter.